# Does Google Container Registry undergo issues?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I am facing an issue while using container optimized VMs. I launch an instance with following command:

```
gcloud compute instances create "$instance_name" \
    --tags "http-server" \
    --image container-vm \
    --scopes storage-rw,logging-write \
    --metadata-from-file google-container-manifest="m2.yml" \
    --zone "$my_zone" \
    --machine-type "$my_machine_type"
```

where `m2.yml` is:

```
version: v1beta2
containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
```

When I ssh to the instance and look into `/var/log/docker.log` I see:

```
time="2015-06-17T07:42:59Z" level=error msg="Handler for GET /containers/{name:.*}/json returned error: no such id: kubelet" 
time="2015-06-17T07:42:59Z" level=error msg="HTTP Error: statusCode=404 no such id: kubelet" 
time="2015-06-17T07:42:59Z" level=info msg="GET /version" 
time="2015-06-17T07:42:59Z" level=info msg="+job version()" 
time="2015-06-17T07:42:59Z" level=info msg="-job version() = OK (0)" 
time="2015-06-17T07:42:59Z" level=info msg="GET /containers/docker-daemon/json" 
time="2015-06-17T07:42:59Z" level=info msg="+job container_inspect(docker-daemon)" 
no such id: docker-daemon
time="2015-06-17T07:42:59Z" level=info msg="-job container_inspect(docker-daemon) = ERR (1)" 
time="2015-06-17T07:42:59Z" level=error msg="Handler for GET /containers/{name:.*}/json returned error: no such id: docker-daemon" 
time="2015-06-17T07:42:59Z" level=error msg="HTTP Error: statusCode=404 no such id: docker-daemon"
```

There is no containers running on the instance and `docker images -a` says:

```
REPOSITORY                       TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              VIRTUAL SIZE
gcr.io/google_containers/pause   0.8.0               2c40b0526b63        11 weeks ago         241.7 kB
<none>                           <none>              56ba5533a2db        11 weeks ago         241.7 kB
<none>                           <none>              511136ea3c5a        2.009460 years ago   0 B
```

Does the container engine undergo some issues or I am doing something wrong?

**Update1**

I gave [an example](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/container_vms#creating_containers_at_time_of_instance_creation) a try:

`version: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: simple-echo
      image: gcr.io/google_containers/busybox
      command: ['nc', '-p', '8080', '-l', '-l', '-e', 'echo', 'hello world!']
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          hostPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
  restartPolicy: Always
  dnsPolicy: Default`

and it is still error in the log:

```
evgeny@instance:~$ cat /var/log/docker.log | grep error
time="2015-06-18T16:28:56Z" level=error msg="Handler for GET /containers/{name:.*}/json returned error: no such id: kubelet" 
time="2015-06-18T16:28:56Z" level=error msg="HTTP Error: statusCode=404 no such id: kubelet" 
time="2015-06-18T16:28:56Z" level=error msg="Handler for GET /containers/{name:.*}/json returned error: no such id: docker-daemon" 
time="2015-06-18T16:28:56Z" level=error msg="HTTP Error: statusCode=404 no such id: docker-daemon" 
time="2015-06-18T16:28:56Z" level=error msg="Handler for GET /images/{name:.*}/json returned error: No such image: gcr.io/google_containers/busybox" 
time="2015-06-18T16:28:56Z" level=error msg="HTTP Error: statusCode=404 No such image: gcr.io/google_containers/busybox" 
time="2015-06-18T16:28:56Z" level=error msg="Handler for GET /containers/{name:.*}/json returned error: no such id: docker" 
time="2015-06-18T16:28:56Z" level=error msg="HTTP Error: statusCode=404 no such id: docker" 
time="2015-06-18T16:28:56Z" level=error msg="Handler for GET /images/{name:.*}/json returned error: No such image: gcr.io/google_containers/busybox" 
time="2015-06-18T16:28:56Z" level=error msg="HTTP Error: statusCode=404 No such image: gcr.io/google_containers/busybox"
```

> I was about to send a feedback via feedback form but Submit fails with: `relay__en.js?authuser=1:182 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'vmFeedbackData' of undefined`. Such a story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest container vm image doesn't support the v1beta2 kubernetes API. You will need to update your manifest to use v1beta3 or v1 (with the corresponding yaml changes).

The latest version of the [container vm documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/container_vms) shows a yaml example using the v1 API.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and the solution turned out to be that I was trying to use

```
securityContext:
  privileged: true
```

Kubernetes doesn't honor that property when loading a docker image onto a GCE instance without using a Google Container cluster (i.e. using a `google-container-manifest` metadata item on a `compute.v1.instance` or a `compute.v1.instanceTemplate`), so it just never loads the image properly onto the instance.

Removing that property solved my problem.